# Woocommerce search some html

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I try to found this code in plugin woocommerce, but i did'nt found

```
<mark class="count">(1)</mark>
```

it's a number count for category product

check http://inst1226908-45105.crystone.net/boutique/

version woocommerce 2.5.1

Comment: It's a class, it's not in the WooCommerce plugin.  What are you trying to do with the number count exactly?

Comment: @user1724434 when update woocomerce 2.51 ,I did'nt found this line in file \woocommerce\templates\content-product_cat     `echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_subcategory_count_html', ' <mark class="count">(' . $category->count . ')</mark>', $category );`

Comment: @user1724434 whencan i found for edite please ?

Answer (score 0):

The html that you are looking for should be in your theme's custom WooCommerce template files /wp-content/theme//woocommerce

Comment: What if there isn't a custom template set up for this?  And - so what if it's in that folder - which file is it?

Answer (score 0):

That code used to be in a template file:

`woocommerce/templates/content-product_cat.php`.

But, as [@silver](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1319623/silver) points out [in his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35073301/870729), in recent changes, it's been moved to a functions file.  **Note:**  *Please see my recommendation at the bottom - this is exactly why you want to do filters, not template modifications.*

If you view the code, you will see that it allows you to [apply_filters](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/apply_filters/) to it, in case you want to modify it.

You would likely want to do that (apply filters) instead of modifying the template, however WooCommerce does offer a [template override system](https://docs.woothemes.com/document/template-structure/) which means that you could create custom versions of templates and locate them in your theme (within a folder title `woocommerce` inside your theme).

If you wanted to modify this output, you'd do it like this.  Add the following to your theme `functions.php` file:

```
add_filter('woocommerce_subcategory_count_html', 'my_subcategory_filter', 10, 2);

function my_subcategory_filter($markup, $category) {
    return '<div class="my_new_class">' . $category->count . ' subcategories</div>';
}
```

**it is my strong recommendation** that you avoid modifying template files *if you can*.  In this case, you *can*, so rather than modifying the template, use the filters.

Why? Because there are OFTEN breaking changes in WooCommerce updates that will cause you to have to update / modify your "custom" templates.  This turns into a lot of work, because Woo updates WooCommerce often, and there are often template updates.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for has been moved to `/woocommerce/includes/wc-template-functions.php`

```
function woocommerce_template_loop_category_title( $category ) {
    ?>
    <h3>
        <?php
            echo $category->name;

            if ( $category->count > 0 )
                echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_subcategory_count_html', ' <mark class="count">(' . $category->count . ')</mark>', $category );
        ?>
    </h3>
    <?php
}
```

You can simply run a filter on `woocommerce_subcategory_count_html`

Comment: I did not find this script in /woocommerce/includes/wc-template-functions.php  i have current version woocommerce 2.5.1

Comment: @books - you don't want to modify it in that file.  Please, read my answer about how to modify the output.

Comment: @boooks, its on line 532 -543, and never ever modify a plugin source file, I only gave you reference so you can see what you can do it it, you can just run a filter, its also a pluggable function so you can also override it by simply creating the same function name

Comment: You see the reference, https://docs.woothemes.com/wc-apidocs/source-function-woocommerce_template_loop_category_title.html#529-543 though it looks like the ```if (function_exists``` has different name, but in the actual release its same name and pluggable

Answer (score 0):

In WooCommerce 2.5.1 this line of code

```
echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_subcategory_count_html', ' <mark class="count">(' . $category->count . ')</mark>', $category );
```

has been moved to woocommerce/includes/wc-template-functions.php on line 539

Comment: Where can find this line please ? i want edite this line

Comment: it's at woocommerce/includes/wc-template-functions.php on line 539